# Where are the flap track covers on this wing?

Tags: aircraft-design, airliner, wing

I don't see it has covers for the flap tracks, so,where are the covers for the flap tracks?

[image: wing]

Image taken from the English for Aviation book (Oxford).

The aircraft is a Vickers VC10

Comment: It appears the shock bodies aren't being used for the flap tracks, as the flaps are only between them and not over them. So there is nothing to cover.

Comment: But wouldn't that result in drag?

Comment: the shock bodies will increase the wet surface and the friction drag but they reduce the wave drag, netly is interesting to include them

Comment: So the flap tracks are uncovered,  that means the wing will have drag? Is it inefficient to have flap tracks uncovered?

Comment: Well yes, if they are not faired, they will add drag... but if we're talking about the pictured wing, we can't see the flap tracks so we don't know how much.

Comment: Mmm yeah. I'll try to figure out which plane is that one.

Comment: Yes. It's a Vickers VC10

Comment: As a side comment, it looks like the aircraft is jettisoning its fuel.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the Vickers VC-10 repair manual:

[image: General arrangement of VC-10 wing]

General arrangement of VC-10 wing (picture [source](http://www.vc10.net/images/wing_srm.jpg)). Note the labelling of the Shock bodies as "flap rail fairings".

The flap tracks were inside the Küchemann bodies and the flaps were between them. This produced gaps between the five flap segments which made them less effective than the modern design of uninterrupted flaps with the flap tracks below them.

Answer (score 1):

They look like Fowler flaps, like on Hercules c130. If that's the case the flaps run on screwjacks and rollers and slip up and into the wing when cursing. All the mechinisums are shrouded by the flaps themselves when retracted and hence no drag. On takeoff and landing the drag is overcome by takeoff thrust and on landing augmented by airbrakes to reduce landing speed. The flap tracks are in the wing and accessable only when the flaps are extended/ deployed.

Comment: Gotta love "cursing" around in an airplane!